# How can i translate a wordpress plugin that doesn't have a .pot file?

Tags: wordpress, translate

My boss wants me to translate the plugin called WeddingPress from English to Danish, but every thing i have searched for says you need a .pot file in the Language folder of the plugin.

This plugin doesn't seem to have one so now i am wondering if there is a way for me to create one for it?
or do i have to go through all the code and Translate everything that way ?

Comment: note that, this plugin did not support translation, when they talked about it 1 year ago on their forum, where they discussed that they would likely open support for WPML, but if that hasn't happened yet, then I would contact them again.

Comment: https://codecanyon.net/item/weddingpress-wordpress-wedding-plugin/9753774/comments?page=3

Comment: [Translate a plugin using .po .mo files](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/57219/12615)

Answer (score 0):

you can use this plugin and you can easily translate your plugin's strings.

Link: [Loco Traslate](https://wordpress.org/plugins/loco-translate/)

Note: you make sure that your plugin strings have looked like this

`_e('Multilingual WordPress Plugin Tutorial', 'text-domain');`

Otherwise, you need to add you string as per above example.